# PHP loop - How to show 2 items with own style and div`s order and then next 2 items with reverse div˙s order and classes

Tags: php, mysql, count

I need to show multiple items with reverse order and different css classes (each item contain two div`s). First two items need to have IMAGE-CONTENT div˙s order then next two items need to have CONTENT - IMAGE div order.?

I am not sure what to do. How to use count/modulus?

Can anyone give simple solution for this?

```
   <?php $result_article = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pm_article WHERE     (id_page = ".$page_id." OR home = 1) AND checked = 1 AND (publish_date IS NULL || publish_date <= ".time().") AND (unpublish_date IS NULL || unpublish_date > ".time().") AND lang = ".LANG_ID." ORDER BY rank");
        if($result_article !== false){
            $nb_articles = $db->last_row_count();

            if($nb_articles > 0){ ?>

        <div class="container-fluid nopadding">

           <div class="isotopeWrapper clearfix isotope">

            <?php
            $article_id = 0;
            $result_article_file = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm_article_file WHERE id_item = :article_id AND checked = 1 AND lang = ".DEFAULT_LANG." AND type = 'image' AND file != '' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1");
            $result_article_file->bindParam(":article_id",$article_id);
            foreach($result_article as $i => $row){
                $article_id = $row['id'];
                $article_title = $row['title'];
                $article_alias = $row['alias'];
                $article_text = strtrunc(strip_tags($row['text']),270);
                $article_tags = $row['tags'];
                $article_page = $row['id_page'];

                if($article_tags != "") $article_tags = " tag".str_replace(","," tag",$article_tags);

                if(isset($pages[$article_page])){

                    $article_alias = DOCBASE.$pages[$article_page]['alias']."/".text_format($article_alias); ?>




                         <article class="article-<?php echo $article_id; ?> col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding isotopeItem <?php echo $article_tags; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">     
                                <div class="isotopeInner">


                                    <?php $sl=1; ?>

                                    <?php if(($sl==1)||($sl==2)) { ?>


                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                            <?php
                                                if($result_article_file->execute() !== false && $db->last_row_count() == 1){
                                                    $row = $result_article_file->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                                                    $file_id = $row['id'];
                                                    $filename = $row['file'];
                                                    $label = $row['label'];

                                                    $realpath = SYSBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                    $thumbpath = DOCBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                    $zoompath = DOCBASE."medias/article/big/".$file_id."/".$filename;

                                                if(is_file($realpath)){ ?>
                                                <figure class="heightfix more-link"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumbpath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $label; ?>" /></a></figure>
                                            <?php } 
                                            } ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding isotopeContent">
                                            <div class="sadrzaj right-triangle heightfix">
                                                <div class="text">
                                                    <h3 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><?php echo $article_title; ?></a></h3>
                                                    <p><?php echo $article_text; ?></p>
                                                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink btn dark"><?php echo $texts['READMORE']; ?></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                    <?php $sl++; } ?>

                                     <?php else { ?>


                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding isotopeContent">
                                            <div class="sadrzaj left-triangle heightfix">
                                                <div class="text">
                                                    <h3 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><?php echo $article_title; ?></a></h3>
                                                    <p><?php echo $article_text; ?></p>
                                                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink btn dark"><?php echo $texts['READMORE']; ?></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                            <?php
                                                if($result_article_file->execute() !== false && $db->last_row_count() == 1){
                                                    $row = $result_article_file->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                                                    $file_id = $row['id'];
                                                    $filename = $row['file'];
                                                    $label = $row['label'];

                                                    $realpath = SYSBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                    $thumbpath = DOCBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                    $zoompath = DOCBASE."medias/article/big/".$file_id."/".$filename;

                                                if(is_file($realpath)){ ?>
                                                <figure class="heightfix more-link"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumbpath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $label; ?>" /></a></figure>
                                            <?php }
                                            } ?>
                                        </div>


                                    <?php if($sl==3 ?>

                                    <?php $sl++; ?>

                                    <?php else; ?>

                                    <?php $sl=1; } ?>

                                    </div>

                            </article>




                    <?php
                }
            } ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php
            }
        } ?>
```

[Screenshoot 1 - This is now and not good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbidC.jpg)

[Screenshoot 2 - I would like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vexOq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `$sl=1;` at the  top

The following logic inside the select query to check the condition

```
if(($sl==1)||($sl==2))
{
   //code for div 1 & 2

    $sl++;   
}
else  //only else is also enough
{

 //code for div 3 & 4
   if($sl==3)
      $sl++;
   else         //$sl=4
     $sl=1;     //reset value of $sl to 1 so the div 1 is shown next
}
```

There will be many ways..just a simple logic i thought of..Try it

**EDIT**
There are a few mistakes in your code
- You have to place `else` in the same `php` tag as soon as the `if` loop is closed.
- `$sl=1` should be placed at the top..Just to initialise it at the beginning
- Did not close the `if` condition braket in `<?php if($sl==3 ?>`
- no semicolen for `else`

```
     <?php 
$sl=1; 
$result_article = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pm_article WHERE     (id_page = ".$page_id." OR home = 1) AND checked = 1 AND (publish_date IS NULL || publish_date <= ".time().") AND (unpublish_date IS NULL || unpublish_date > ".time().") AND lang = ".LANG_ID." ORDER BY rank");
            if($result_article !== false){
                $nb_articles = $db->last_row_count();

                if($nb_articles > 0){ ?>

            <div class="container-fluid nopadding">

               <div class="isotopeWrapper clearfix isotope">

                <?php
                $article_id = 0;
                $result_article_file = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm_article_file WHERE id_item = :article_id AND checked = 1 AND lang = ".DEFAULT_LANG." AND type = 'image' AND file != '' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1");
                $result_article_file->bindParam(":article_id",$article_id);
                foreach($result_article as $i => $row){
                    $article_id = $row['id'];
                    $article_title = $row['title'];
                    $article_alias = $row['alias'];
                    $article_text = strtrunc(strip_tags($row['text']),270);
                    $article_tags = $row['tags'];
                    $article_page = $row['id_page'];

                    if($article_tags != "") $article_tags = " tag".str_replace(","," tag",$article_tags);

                    if(isset($pages[$article_page])){

                        $article_alias = DOCBASE.$pages[$article_page]['alias']."/".text_format($article_alias); ?>




                             <article class="article-<?php echo $article_id; ?> col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding isotopeItem <?php echo $article_tags; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">     
                                    <div class="isotopeInner">




                                        <?php if(($sl==1)||($sl==2)) { ?>


                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                                <?php
                                                    if($result_article_file->execute() !== false && $db->last_row_count() == 1){
                                                        $row = $result_article_file->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                                                        $file_id = $row['id'];
                                                        $filename = $row['file'];
                                                        $label = $row['label'];

                                                        $realpath = SYSBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                        $thumbpath = DOCBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                        $zoompath = DOCBASE."medias/article/big/".$file_id."/".$filename;

                                                    if(is_file($realpath)){ ?>
                                                    <figure class="heightfix more-link"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumbpath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $label; ?>" /></a></figure>
                                                <?php } 
                                                } ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding isotopeContent">
                                                <div class="sadrzaj right-triangle heightfix">
                                                    <div class="text">
                                                        <h3 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><?php echo $article_title; ?></a></h3>
                                                        <p><?php echo $article_text; ?></p>
                                                        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink btn dark"><?php echo $texts['READMORE']; ?></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                     <?php
                                         $sl++; 
                                         }
                                        else 
                                          { ?>


                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding isotopeContent">
                                                <div class="sadrzaj left-triangle heightfix">
                                                    <div class="text">
                                                        <h3 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><?php echo $article_title; ?></a></h3>
                                                        <p><?php echo $article_text; ?></p>
                                                        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink btn dark"><?php echo $texts['READMORE']; ?></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                                <?php
                                                    if($result_article_file->execute() !== false && $db->last_row_count() == 1){
                                                        $row = $result_article_file->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                                                        $file_id = $row['id'];
                                                        $filename = $row['file'];
                                                        $label = $row['label'];

                                                        $realpath = SYSBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                        $thumbpath = DOCBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                                        $zoompath = DOCBASE."medias/article/big/".$file_id."/".$filename;

                                                    if(is_file($realpath)){ ?>
                                                    <figure class="heightfix more-link"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumbpath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $label; ?>" /></a></figure>
                                                <?php }
                                                } ?>
                                            </div>


                                        <?php if($sl==3) 
                                         $sl++; 
                                          else 
                                            $sl=1; ?>

                                        </div>

                                </article>




                        <?php
                    }
                } ?>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php
                }
            } ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on this part of code:
 
}
else if(($sl==3)||($sl==4) 
{

Comment: @user2114900 you did not close 1 bracket.. it should be ` if(($sl==3)||($sl==4)) { `

Comment: stil not good

<div class="isotopeInner">
       
       
       <?php if(($sl==1)||($sl==2)) { ?>
       code 1

          <?php $sl++; ?> 
       
       <?php } else if(($sl==3)||($sl==4)){ ?>

        //2
       <?php if($sl==3) ?>
        
          <?php $sl++; ?>
          
       <?php else ?>       
          <?php$sl=1; } ?>
       
       
       
       
        

       </div>

On last else I got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Comment: then just leave it as else instead of else if

Comment: @user2114900 See my edit...Remove the condition from else

Comment: @user2114900 post the current error..its not with the logic..You might have missed something small

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Comment: post your updated code..you might have closed a brace additionally

Comment: Yes! I just changed two elements as it is written in my answer. Workng code posted. Thank you so much, appreciate it!

Comment: @user2114900 Welcome...Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

First error was with position of $sl=1 .It must be positioned at top of second query. Further more There is also one variable which must be closed with } bracket at the end of loop. This is working code now. Thank you for your assist @affaz i appreciate it.

```
<?php
        $result_article = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pm_article WHERE (id_page = ".$page_id." OR home = 1) AND checked = 1 AND (publish_date IS NULL || publish_date <= ".time().") AND (unpublish_date IS NULL || unpublish_date > ".time().") AND lang = ".LANG_ID." ORDER BY rank");
        if($result_article !== false){
            $nb_articles = $db->last_row_count();

            if($nb_articles > 0){ ?>

    <div class="container-fluid nopadding">

            <?php $sl=1;  ?>

            <?php
            $article_id = 0;
            $result_article_file = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm_article_file WHERE id_item = :article_id AND checked = 1 AND lang = ".DEFAULT_LANG." AND type = 'image' AND file != '' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1");
            $result_article_file->bindParam(":article_id",$article_id);
            foreach($result_article as $i => $row){
                $article_id = $row['id'];
                $article_title = $row['title'];
                $article_alias = $row['alias'];
                $article_text = strtrunc(strip_tags($row['text']),270);
                $article_tags = $row['tags'];
                $article_page = $row['id_page'];

                if($article_tags != "") $article_tags = " tag".str_replace(","," tag",$article_tags);

                if(isset($pages[$article_page])){

                    $article_alias = DOCBASE.$pages[$article_page]['alias']."/".text_format($article_alias); ?>

                      <?php if(($sl==1)||($sl==2)) { ?>


                        <div class="article-<?php echo $article_id; ?> col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 nopadding itemi <?php echo $article_tags; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                <?php
                                    if($result_article_file->execute() !== false && $db->last_row_count() == 1){
                                        $row = $result_article_file->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                                        $file_id = $row['id'];
                                        $filename = $row['file'];
                                        $label = $row['label'];

                                        $realpath = SYSBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                        $thumbpath = DOCBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                        $zoompath = DOCBASE."medias/article/big/".$file_id."/".$filename;

                                    if(is_file($realpath)){ ?>
                                    <figure class="heightfix more-link"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><img src="<?php echo $zoompath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $label; ?>" /></a></figure>
                                <?php } 
                                } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                <div class="sadrzaj left-triangle heightfix">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><?php echo $article_title; ?></a></h3>
                                        <p><?php echo $article_text; ?></p>
                                        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink btn dark"><?php echo $texts['READMORE']; ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>  



                         <?php
                                     $sl++; 
                                     }
                                    else 
                                      { ?>


                        <div class="article-<?php echo $article_id; ?> col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 nopadding itemi <?php echo $article_tags; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">   
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                <div class="sadrzaj right-triangle heightfix">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><?php echo $article_title; ?></a></h3>
                                        <p><?php echo $article_text; ?></p>
                                        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink btn dark"><?php echo $texts['READMORE']; ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 nopadding">
                                <?php
                                    if($result_article_file->execute() !== false && $db->last_row_count() == 1){
                                        $row = $result_article_file->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                                        $file_id = $row['id'];
                                        $filename = $row['file'];
                                        $label = $row['label'];

                                        $realpath = SYSBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                        $thumbpath = DOCBASE."medias/article/small/".$file_id."/".$filename;
                                        $zoompath = DOCBASE."medias/article/big/".$file_id."/".$filename;

                                    if(is_file($realpath)){ ?>
                                    <figure class="heightfix more-link"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $article_alias; ?>" class="moreLink"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $zoompath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $label; ?>" /></a></figure>
                                <?php }
                                } ?>
                            </div>

                        </div>


        <?php if($sl==3) 
                                     $sl++; 
                                      else 
                                        $sl=1; }?>

                    <?php
                }
            } ?>

    </div>
    <?php
            }
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Increment the value of `for` loop by 2

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i+=2)
    {
      if($i%2==0)
      {
        //code for 1st and 2nd div
        <div class="row"> <!-- FIRST AND SECOND DIV -->
        <div class="item"> 
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-1 IMAGE">
              <img alt="" src="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-1 CONTENT">
              <p>Content</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item"> 
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-1 IMAGE">
              <img alt="" src="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-1 CONTENT">
              <p>Content</p>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   }
   else
   {
     //code for 3rd and 4th div
    <div class="row"> <!-- THIRD AND FOURTH DIV-->
       <div class="item">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-2 CONTENT">
               <p>Content</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-2 IMAGE">
               <img alt="" src="" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-2 CONTENT">
               <p>Content</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 class-2 IMAGE">
               <img alt="" src="" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
  </div>
      </div>
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. For me this shows same layout (from 1st and 2nd) for all other items. Is there any chance to make correction for this? If you need full code I can make update.

Comment: @affkaz Actually it constantly loop from first part of code before PHP ELSE

Comment: @user2114900 there lot in the code..with 2 select query.I cant sort out what each is for.first try out in a small code and then implement to the entire one

Comment: @user2114900 What is shown now after adding the for loop..could you post the screenshot of it

Comment: screenshoots added to first post

Comment: @user2114900 Some logic would be needed for it..let me try